# Unreacheable JS part

Tags: javascript

I have one form, one controller and JS part. For some reasons (I don't know why) it doesnt see JS part. Maybe someone can help me to solve the problem.

Form looks like:

```
<head>
    <title>Cabinet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="worker name" name="worker-name" type="text"
                                       id="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="worker title" name="worker-title"
                                       type="text" id="title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="worker salary" name="worker-salary"
                                       type="number" id="salary">
                            </div>
                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="CREATE"
                                   id="createWorker">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/createWorker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller. `logger.info` is not showing on the console.

```
@WebServlet ("/worker")
public class WorkerController extends HttpServlet {

    private WorkerService workerService;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WorkerController.class);

    public WorkerController() {
        workerService = new WorkerServiceImpl();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  logger.info("TEST");
        String name = req.getParameter("workerName");
        String title = req.getParameter("workerTitle");
        int salary = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("workerSalary"));

        Worker worker = new Worker(name, title, salary);
        logger.info("POST /worker request: " + worker);
        workerService.create(worker);
        //TODO : create handler (bootstrap component) if product is created
        resp.setContentType("text");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().write("Success");
    }
}
```

In this JS part `console.log`  is empty

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#createWorker").click(function () {
        var name = $("form input.name").val();
        console.log(name);
        var title = $("form input.title").val();
        console.log(title);
        var salary  = $("form input.salary").val();
        console.log(salary);
        if (name == '' || title == '' || salary == '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else {
            var worker = {
                workerName: name,
                workerTitle: title,
                workerSalary: salary
            };
            $.post("worker", worker, function (data) {
                if (data === 'Success') {
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                }
            });
            alert("Worker:" + worker.workerName + " was created")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need input#name, not input.name. name is an ID, not class.

Comment: @Gogol the problem was in `$("button#createWorker").click(function ()`. I change to
`$("form input#createWorker").click(function ()` and all works.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your css selectors are wrong. You already have `id`s on those fields, try and [select by id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#createWorker").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        console.log(name);
        var title = $("#title").val();
        console.log(title);
        var salary  = $("#salary").val();
        console.log(salary);
        if (name == '' || title == '' || salary == '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else {
            var worker = {
                workerName: name,
                workerTitle: title,
                workerSalary: salary
            };
            $.post("worker", worker, function (data) {
                if (data === 'Success') {
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                }
            });
            alert("Worker:" + worker.workerName + " was created")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem was in $("button#createWorker").click(function (). I change to $("form input#createWorker").click(function () and all works